# Is teflon a poison if ingested?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers

Nowadays, a lot of frying pans are made with a *non-stick* coating. That's usually teflon, or chemically speaking polytetrafluorethylene - $\ce{(C2F4)}_n$. Can you be poisoned if some of that teflon gets in your meal by scraping the pan or in any other way? And if so, what happens (chemically speaking) in your body after ingestion?

Comment: Teflon is very inert and small pieces in the body will not be absorbed, so no. The only way to suffer from it is to overheat the pan enough to thermolyse the teflon back to the monomer, which is harmful (though less so to people than birds).

Comment: @matt_black Thanks, your comment was useful. Would you mind forming it into na answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I am not breaking any rules of this forum by directly quoting, but here you go:

"The cold polymer is harmless on ingestion, in contact
with the skin, or implanted in living tissues. When
heated above 250° C. it begins slowly to give rise to
small amounts of decomposition products, some of
which are toxic.
The accidental inhalation of fumes from the overheated
polymer by workmen produces an influenza-like
illness which has been described elsewhere. The
illness follows a latent interval of a few hours and
resolves within a day or two with no subsequent illeffects.
This may happen, for example, when the
polymer is heated to comparatively high temperatures
(350-400 C.) in an oven, an extruder, or some other
equipment used to fabricate it, but it is easily prevented
by the intelligent use of exhaust ventilation."

In: Harris, Kenwin. “Toxicity of Polytetrafluoroethylene.” British Medical Journal 1.5285 (1962): 1146.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1958415/pdf/brmedj02864-0082a.pdf

Comment: Well we can conclude not to overheat it or we can poison ourselves!